# Laravel 5.5 Session::put() stores 'favicon.ico'

Tags: php, laravel, session, middleware

I have the next code:

```
    /*
    * If the route has someroute/en
    * where en is the lang of the page
    */
    $locale = $request->route('locale');
    if ( $locale != null ) {
        // 1. dd($locale)
        Session::put('_lang', $locale);
    } else {

        dd($request->session());
    }
```

So when I run the code without the 1. commented, I got "en". Then I removed that dd($locale), and let run the Session:put(). So when I go to a route or the same removing the /en from the route I got 'favicon.ico' instead of 'en'.
Does anyone have any idea of why this is happening?

Extra: I'm using this on a middleware, that is on the 'web' array. Also I'm using file as my session storage.

Comment: This might be an indication that your rewrite rules are messing up and catching `favicon.ico` as a framework request rather than a static resource (or that you don't have a `favicon.ico` file)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you write the full path to your favicon.ico
For Emx.

```
<link href="http://www.example.com/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">
```

or

```
<link href="{{asset('/favicon.ico')}}" rel="shortcut icon">
```

NOT only file name like ( `href="favicon.ico"` )

Also make sure you have this file in your 'public' or 'public_html' root.

Laravel adds an empty favicon.ico file (0KB) in  to avoid these problems.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @apokryfos

I did not have a favicon.ico under my 'public' directory.